# Windows: Feed a Webrtc Stream to a Virtual Driver

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, webrtc

I have a virtual webcam installed on Win 10 and I am using [this project](https://github.com/valarpirai/video-chat-app) link to get the remote webrtc stream.

My goal is instead of sending the stream to video element I need to send it to my virtual driver.

So here is the html element

```
setTheirVideo : function (stream) {
        var video = document.getElementById('their-video');
        if (typeof video.srcObject == "object") {
            video.srcObject = stream;
        } else {
            video.src = URL.createObjectURL(stream);
        }
    },
```

Where & How would I set the stream to be sent to the driver API instead of HTML Element?
for example:
MyDriver.SetData(stream);

Please let me know if anyone has already accomplished this.

Comment: What are you exactly trying to accomplish? Are you trying to get a remote users webcam into OBS (or some tool like that). I don't fully understand what is `send to my virtual driver`.

Comment: No I am not using obs. We have our own virtual video driver and I need to send samples received from remote peer to driver instead of sending it to html element or a canvas. 1) is there a event that triggers for every sample or frame received from remote peer? Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Comment: @SeanDuBois: Any help if possible?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible in the browser. It sounds like `send to my virtual driver` will require hardware access. You will probably need to use a WebRTC implementation outside the browser.

Comment: I have converted it to an electron app https://github.com/EbramTawfik/video-chat-app. My question is how can I get access to raw samples received from the remote? I already know how to send samples to driver but don't know how to get the raw samples from remote. Any info is appreciated.